# Android Google Cloud Messaging gem for Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a new gem for ruby on rails for GCM earlier known as C2DM.

If not then, should we continue to use the old gem for C2DM like one here on [github](https://github.com/pimeys/c2dm_on_rails)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails

Comment: I found this gem to work but the documentation is poor.  What it fails to mention in the example is that `notification.data = {:registration_ids => ["RegistrationID"], :data => {:message_text => "Get on cloud nine"}}` the `registration_ids` needs to have the registration id of the device (obviously now but was not when I started).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this si https://github.com/kureikain/sinatra-gcm. It comes with a WebUI let you create and send notification in JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my gem: https://github.com/tompesman/push-core

This gem allows you to send messages to APNS, GCM and C2DM.